# parsing numerical address

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to parse a numerical address from a string using regex.

So far, I have been able to successfully get the numerical address (partially) 63.88.73.26:80 from the string http://63.88.73.26:80/. However I have been trying to skip over the :80/, and have had no luck.

What I have tried so far is:

```
Pattern.compile("[0-999].*[0-999][\\p{Digit}]", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

however does still includes :80

I dont know what I am missing here, I have tried to check for \p{Digit} at the end, but that doesn't do much either

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why would you not tokenize at punctuation and then deal with the entries?

Comment: The `.*` is consuming the colon. I would suggest using `"[0-9\\.]*"`.

Comment: Does it really have to be regex? Java provides URL class. You can use it like `new URL("http://63.88.73.26:80/").getHost()` to get `63.88.73.26` part.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to learn Regex (although slowly).... What RamenChef posted worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a *positive look ahead* `(?=...)`.  This will match only if it is followed by a specific expression, the one in the *positive look ahead*'s parenthesis.  In it's simplest form you could have

```
[0-9\.]+(?=:[0-9]{0,4})
```

Though you may want to change the `[0-9\.]+` part (match 1 or more digit or full stop) with something more complete to check that you have a properly formed address

Check out regexr.com where you can fiddle your expression to your heart's content until it works...

Answer (score 1):

Note that Pshemo indicated the right approach with `URL` and [`getHost()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost()):

> Gets the host name of this URL, if applicable. The format of the host conforms to RFC 2732, i.e. for a literal IPv6 address, this method will return the IPv6 address enclosed in square brackets (`'['` and `']'`).

Thus, it is best to use the proper tool here:

```
import java.net.*;
....
String str = new URL("http:" + "//63.88.73.26:80/").getHost(); 
System.out.println(str); // => 63.88.73.26
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/fKNbyJ)

You mention that you want to learn regex, so let's inspect your pattern:

- `[0-999]` - matches any 1 digit, a single digit (`0-9` creates a range that matches `0`..`9`, and the two `9`s are redundant and can be removed)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, greedily, i.e. up to the last...
- `[0-999]` - see above (any 1 digit)
- `[\\p{Digit}]` - any Unicode digit

That means, you match a string starting with a digit and up to the last occurrence of 2 consecutive digits.

You need a sequence of digits and dots. There are multiple ways to extract such strings.

1. Using verbose pattern with exact character specification together with how many occurrences you need: [`[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}`](http://ideone.com/HKqoqS) (the whole match - `matcher.group()` - holds the required value).
2. Using the "brute-force" character class approach (see [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894161/3832970)), but I'd use a *capturing group* instead of a lookahead and use an unescaped dot since inside a character class it is treated as a literal dot: [`([0-9.]+):[0-9]`](http://ideone.com/oBtNXF) (now, the value is in `matcher.group(1)`)
3. A "fancy" "get-string-between-two-strings" approach: all text other than `:` and `/` between `http://` and `:` must be captured into a group - [`https?://([^:/]+):`](http://ideone.com/g6bN3T) (again, the value is in `matcher.group(1)`)

Some sample code (Approach #1):

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,3}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher("http://63.88.73.26:80/");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Must read: [*Character Classes or Character Sets*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).